# how to write awk code with specific condition

Tags: linux, if-statement, unix, awk

I want to create a code that operates on a certain number of a row of data, for which I just want to count negative numbers to make them positive by multiplying by the number itself negative
example

data

```
10
11
-12
-13
-14
```

expected output

```
10
11
144
169
196
```

this is what I've been try

```
awk 'int($0)<0 {$4 = int($0) + 360} 
     END {print $4}' data.txt
```

but I don't even get the output, anyone can help me?

Comment: Why are you only printing in the `END` block? That runs just once at the end of the file, not for each line.

Comment: Why are you adding 360 when you said you wanted to multiply the number by itself?

Comment: awk 'int($1)<0 {$4=int($1*$1)} {print $4}' data.txt

output:


144
169
196

this code is run as well, but then how to display unoperated data along with multiplied data?

Comment: Why are you using `$4` when the line only has 1 field?

Comment: I defined it to be a new line

Comment: When the number is positive, you don't assign anything to `$4`, so `print $4` doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$0 < 0 { $0 = $0 * $0 } 1' data.txt
```

The first condition multiplies the value by itself when it's negative. The condition `1` is always true, so the line is printed unconditionally.

Comment: This will replace empty lines with `0`. You can fix that with `$0 && $0 < $0 {...` if neccesary.

Comment: On my Mac terminal I must use curly brackets outside as well: `awk '{if ($0 < 0) {$0 = $0*$0 } print $0}' file`

Comment: @Supertech no, you don't, no awk requires that (except maybe old, broken awk on Solaris). If you think you do then there's some other problem that this is working around, probably mismatched quotes or something in whatever script you're calling awk from.

Comment: `$0 = $0 * $0` = `$0 *= $0`

Comment: @Ed Morton you were right. I must have been making a mistake or sth weird happened that I did not notice for the first time I tried it. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
awk '{print($0<0)?$0*$0:$0}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also match only digits that start with `-` and in that case multiply them by themselves

```
awk '{print (/^-[0-9]+$/ ? $0 * $0 : $0)}' data.txt
```

Output

```
10
11
144
169
196
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print $0 ^ (/-/ ? 2 : 1)}' file
10
11
144
169
196
```

Comment: Ah I see, the `^` is exponentiation by either 2 or 1. You might also make it more specific `/^-[0-9]` but it does get the required result.

Comment: Right, `^` is the POSIX exponent notation. GNU awk also supports `**` for the same purpose but idk why as it's 1 char longer and no clearer. No need to change it given the posted sample input, and if the OPs real data doesn't look like the example then there's other cases it also might contain that we'd have to consider.